# Command works in bash but not fabric

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, fabric

I'm working with fabric and python 3.6 on on a ubuntu 16.04 VPS. I have the following fabric function:

```
    run(f'conda env list')
```

which gives output:

```
[deploy@mysite.com] run: conda env list
[deploy@mysite.com] out: /bin/bash: conda: command not found
```

However when I ssh in to the vps and run it in bash it works:

```
deploy@server:~$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
root                  *  /home/deploy/miniconda3
```

How can I get this working in fabric

Comment: Specify the full path to `conda`. PATH is being updated to include conda somewhere that's only updated in interactive shells.

Comment: Thanks that worked, I had updated the path to miniconda in my .bashrc. Would you like to enter it as an answer?